# How to connect makefiles for two folders/projects that must be run both together and independent

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following issue:
I got one folder, let's say /trunk/modules/mymodule which contains my project that I must build using a buildsystem and I have the /trunk/libs/mylib folder with it's own .cpp and .h files.

My module will need to use the library that I am building in /libs/mylib, but that library will also be used by other projects. So I want whenever I build my project I also check if the library is updated(and rebuild it is there are changes), but I want the makefiles in the library to be able to be run independently, so someone can just update the library or use it with another module.

I have 2 Makefiles.in, i connect them by calling include ../../lib/mylib/Makefile in the first one and use -L same path -lmylib when linking my project which will also be a .so library.

I logically get  `warning: overriding recipe for target 'distclean'` and

```
warning: overriding recipe for target 'clean'
```

for the clean and make distclean which are defined in both makefiles.

How do I get around that? And is it even possible?

Comment: Instead of including `lib/mylib/Makefile` you can simply run `$(MAKE) -C ../../lib/mylib/Makefile` from `modules/mymodule/Makefile`, e.g. for a phony target `mylib`

Comment: found out the $(MAKE) , thanks, and I presume i there is a similar solution for the clean and distclean targest in the main module makefile. Oh, and without the include I will not have the warning and the problem with 2 targets - i will make changes and try it now, looked at the $(MAKE) ../../mylib/makefile clean solution to call clean and distclean from the module in the second one, but that wasn't fixing the double target.

Comment: Missing [MCVE]. So give at least your `Makefile.in`s

Comment: Can't post what I write for company, the problem is in the description. I think bodo's comment may have fixed the first issue, must also modify the make clean and make distclean to call a recursvie make and I think I am done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including your library Makefile `lib/mylib/Makefile` you can use recursive MAKE by running

```
$(MAKE) -C ../../lib/mylib/Makefile
```

from your main module's Makefile `modules/mymodule/Makefile`.

You could use a similar solutions for targets `clean` or `distclean`

You could use a phony target `mylib` like this:

```
.PHONY: mylib all clean
LIBDIR=../../lib/mylib

all: mymodule

mymodule: mylib
        ...

mylib:
        $(MAKE) -C $(LIBDIR)

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(LIBDIR) $@
        ...
```

Note: If you copy code from this example to a `Makefile`, change the indentation to use a tab instead of spaces.

You might also consider using a top level `Makefile` in `trunk` that recursively calls `make` in `lib/mylib` and `modules/mymodule`.

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion

Some consider recursive make as harmful, but this depends on how exactly you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Non-recursive way:
If you control all the makefiles and can rewrite those completely, then I'd suggest you to look at https://github.com/cppfw/prorab

It allows having independent makefiles for neighbor projects and also including one makefile into another and adding the compilation dependency.
See WIKI in the github repo.

Basically, you add the dependency of your executable on some `libmylib.so` and also include the makefile which builds that library.